# working with python dictionaries created from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, shuffle

I'm trying to manipulate the order of a csv file after certain rules with the following code. The error message is

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I transformed the csv rows into python dictionaries. The problem is that in the following steps, the program does not take the dictionaries but single strings and I can not save the manipulated order as a csv file again. My input csv looks like this:

```
ID      Typ      Target
S01_a   a        example1
S01_b   b        example2
S02_a   a        example3
S02_b   b        example4
S03_a   a        example5
S03_b   b        example6
...     ...      ...
```

```
import pandas as pd

#import data
df=pd.read_csv('stimuli.csv')


#Convert Data Frame to Dictionary
df2dict=df.set_index('ID').transpose().to_dict(orient='dict')

### make two blocks of stimuli
import random

Block1 = []
Block2 = []
for item in df2dict:
    if not any(item[0:3] == el[0:3] for el in Block1):
        Block1.append(item)
    else:
        Block2.append(item)


### same number of conditions in each block       
Block1[0:15], Block2[0:15] = Block2[0:15], Block1[0:15]


### no two times a stimuli in the a condition in a row
while True:
    Block1

    shuffle1 = []

    last = ""

    while Block1:
        l = Block1
        if last:
            l = [x for x in l if x[-1] != last[-1]]
        if not l:
            #no valid solution
            break 
        newEl = random.choice(l)
        last = newEl
        shuffle1.append(newEl)
        Block1.remove(newEl)
    if not Block1:
        break


### same for Block2, no two times the same condition in a row      
while True:
    Block2

    shuffle2 = []

    last2 = ""

    while Block2:
        m = Block2
        if last2:
            m = [x for x in m if x[-1] != last2[-1]]
        if not m:
            #no valid solution
            break 
        newEl = random.choice(m)
        last2 = newEl
        shuffle2.append(newEl)
        Block2.remove(newEl)
    if not Block2:
        break

### join the two blocks

full_list = shuffle1+shuffle2


### save into a new csv

csv_columns = ['ID','Typ', 'Target']
csv_file = "Names.csv"
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in full_list:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error") 
print(df2dict)
```

The desired output would be a csv data file with the new order of the stimuli; two blocks (if S01_a is in block one, then S01_b is in the second block) and no two conditions (a vs. b) in a row. It would have to look like this:

```
ID      Typ     Target
S02_a   a       example3
S01_b   b       example2
S03_a   a       example5
S02_b   b       example4
S01_a   a       example1
S03_b   b       example6
...     ...     ...
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may have a nicer time just working with pandas (since I see you have it already installed). If you want I can still provide `csv` code but can you provide the desired output?

Comment: which line is the error ocurring? Also, If iterating at dictionaries i believe it would be better to go as `for key, value from df2dict.items():`

Comment: Until ###save into a new csv everything is working, but just for the ID names and not for the whole dictionaries

Comment: Oh, sometimes it bugs .csvs if the first 2 columns are "ID". Try renaming it.

Comment: Also, why not trying to save from pandas dataframe? `pd.DataFrame(full_list, columns=csv_columns).to_csv(csv_file)`

Comment: What should I rename it in? @mrbTT your saving method raises this error with my data: "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 3"

Comment: Oh, try like this then: `pd.DataFrame([full_list], columns=csv_columns).to_csv(csv_file)`.  The rename should be anything other than "ID". Thats up to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this gives me that error: "AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 61 columns" changing the 'ID' leads to a key error

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I added the desired output

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I don't see a desired output, I see a vague explenation (we know nothing about your project nor do we understand your terminology)... Make sure you dont explain your output, post a formatted text block of what you expect. All I care about is the csv input and the desired output (as formatted text).